# Creating a linked list to enroll students in C

Tags: c, linked-list

In parser.h:

```
typedef enum _SEX {MALE = 'M', FEMALE = 'F', OTHER = 'O'} SEX;

struct course {
 char grade;
 unsigned int number;
 struct course *next;
};

struct student {
  char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  unsigned int age;
  SEX sex;
  float gpa;
  struct course *courses;
  struct student *next;
 };
```

In parser.c: 
I have a function struct student * enroll_student(...) which I cannot change. This function creates a new student and store it in its appropriate position (following dictionary order) in the list. This is what I have so far.... 
MY question: I don't know how to access the enum SEX and I do not know if this is the correct approach. 
Any feedback or help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

```
   /*globally declared*/
   static struct student *head; 

struct student* enroll_student(char *name, unsigned int age, SEX sex, float gpa){

 struct student *enroll = NULL;
   /*allocate memory*/
    enroll = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct));

  if(enroll != NULL){
    /*INITIALIZE*/
    strncpy(enroll->name, name, MAX_NAME_LEN);
    enroll->age = age; 
    /* How do I access the ENUM SEX?*/
    enroll->gpa = gpa; 
    enroll->next = NULL;

   }
   return enroll;
```

}

Comment: You're missing the code to add it to the linked list.

Comment: @harper Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender

Comment: @harper perhaps Hermaphrodite?

Comment: Why not use typedef for student struct and course struct?

Comment: @AAB because these structs were predefined, i am not allowed to change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enroll_student` function is **not** for inserting anything in a linked list. The purpose of the function is to a) create a new student object and b) initialize the object. So it is a function that you call when you want a new student object but the code for inserting student objects in a linked list has to be added outside the function. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 100

typedef enum _SEX {MALE = 'M', FEMALE = 'F', OTHER = 'O'} SEX;

struct course {
  char grade;
  unsigned int number;
  struct course *next;
};

struct student {
  char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  unsigned int age;
  SEX sex;
  float gpa;
  struct course *courses;
  struct student *next;
};

struct student* enroll_student(char *name, unsigned int age, SEX sex, float gpa){
  struct student *enroll = NULL;
  /*allocate memory*/
  enroll = malloc(sizeof *enroll);

  if(enroll != NULL){
    /*INITIALIZE*/
    strncpy(enroll->name, name, MAX_NAME_LEN);
    enroll->age = age;
    enroll->sex = sex;
    enroll->gpa = gpa;
    enroll->courses = NULL;
    enroll->next = NULL;

  }
  return enroll;
}

int main(void) {
  static struct student *head = NULL;
  struct student* st;

  // Make a new student
  st = enroll_student("Bart", 21, MALE, 1.0);

  // Insert in front of list
  st->next = head;
  head = st;

  // Make a new student
  st = enroll_student("Kim", 25, FEMALE, 1.0);

  // Insert in front of list
  st->next = head;
  head = st;

  // Print all students in the list
  struct student* tmp = head;
  while (tmp)
  {
    printf("Name: %s\n", tmp->name);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }

  // Free allocated memory
  while (head)
  {
    tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Kim
Name: Bart
```